# Accessing Fragment Area in shader

Tags: glsl, vulkan

The vulkan spec defines `Fragment Area` as `The width and height, in pixels, of a fragment`. Is there a way to access this width and height in the fragment shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial fulltext search of the specification gives me `FragSizeEXT`. Perhaps that one is applicable?

Comment: GLSL code to use this would be `#version 450

#extension GL_EXT_fragment_invocation_density : enable


void main()
{
    ivec2 wh = gl_FragSizeEXT;
}`